# Swift 3 "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am getting this aforementioned error. I've applied the following solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200562/swift-thread-1-signal-sigabrt) and that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628892/swift-thread-1-signal-sigabrt) with no avail. Is there some module or class I'm suppose to import? Any help will be appreciated.

Github: https://github.com/joeavargas/BMI-Calc/tree/master/BMI%20Calc

Swift 3 / Xcode 8.3.3

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2FvE.png)

Error from Console:

2017-07-06 08:20:28.252 BMI Calc[61662:12276419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mass.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df6eb0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b2fe141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df6ea59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ae1400b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b96b994 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010bbd8a09 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df14e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010bbd73bf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b971fc3 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b9728d9 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b972c0a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b97345a -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b83b98a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b83c070 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b84eebe -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b7c837f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b7ce5e4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b7cb7f3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f67e5f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f67e46d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f67e7f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df14c01 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010defa0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010def95ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010def9016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010b7ca08f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b7d0134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  BMI Calc                            0x000000010ad246f7 main + 55
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ef0e65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Could you please share what it says in the debug log

Comment: Most likely there is a missing or dead connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: Added the error from console. Sorry for the delayed reply...I work night shifts and I just woke up a few minutes ago.

Comment: The error is `reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mass.'` When you have `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT” error` issue, you should usually search for **reason** in the console using `cmmd + F`. As for the solution to your error: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: @honey I'll look into your suggestion. Something tells me the link you provided may may help a lot. It also has very good advice about using the word "String"

Answer (score 0):

The most significant information is

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **mass**.

- Select the storyboard or xib file in the project navigator
- Select the view controller
- Open Connection Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘6</kbd>)
- Remove the connection to `mass`

Comment: I see two mass connections as an option to remove. I assume I remove the one that's not declared/used in the code?